how to get all Program tokens in ProgramID in Solana network mainnet ecosystem with javascript
Hi I want to get all Program tokens in a ProgramId, but I get an error here errors 401: it seems this error is rpc does not allow access to the getProgramAccounts method how can I fix it?
const { Connection, PublicKey } = require('@solana/web3.js');

(async () => {
  const connection = new Connection('https://solana-api.projectserum.com', 'confirmed'); 

  try {
    const accounts = await connection.getParsedProgramAccounts(
      new PublicKey("6EF8rrecthR5Dkzon8Nwu78hRvfCKubJ14M5uBEwF6P"),
      {
        filters: [
          {
            dataSize: 165, // số byte
          }
        ],
      }
    );

    if (accounts.length === 0) {
      console.log("No token accounts found.");
      return;
    }

    console.log(`Found ${accounts.length} token account(s):`);
    accounts.forEach((account, i) => {
      console.log(`-- Token Account Address ${i + 1}: ${account.pubkey.toString()} --`);
      const parsedData = account.account.data["parsed"];
      if (!parsedData) {
        console.log("Account data is not parsed.");
        return;
      }
      console.log(`Mint: ${parsedData["info"]["mint"]}`);
      console.log(`Amount: ${parsedData["info"]["tokenAmount"]["uiAmount"]}`);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching token accounts:', error);
  }
})();

The result I expected was like this:
[
{
"mint": "9kiV39kX1cpyimyk3msDw1VM9ua6M6ATikp1iuZZpump",
"name": "HOLY INTERGALACTIC MONKEY",
"symbol": "$HIM",
"description": "I'M $HIM.",
"image_uri": "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmT1JeMxSenC1f7FidfwLFyhiKTSVjZXoXcrAUdaBSsk69",
"metadata_uri": "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmYTKtkMHoo2bTWTUMZ4KjAAdJxuNVxueNw5QqhmuQkV32",
},
{
"mint": "6SXt5N7Z8B25EQopdQEFpwxvA6fLedxef7nMAU8Bpump",
"name": "Fwukong",
"symbol": "FWUKONG",
"description": "Meet FWUKONG, also known as the Monkey King.  One of the most enduring Chinese literary characters. ",
"image_uri": "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmXK4zvVGW3X9j51oToke7T3vkQqADM6VhohrUx3qcqM9S",
"metadata_uri": "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/Qma36d8mLmKRXQuEEc4PcbwSShbWPWAMSRZ45vCcdZASuU",
}
I'm just trying to learn, hope everyone gently helps

Most public endpoints like https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com or https://solana-api.projectserum.com have the getProgramsAccounts call ratelimited or disabled because its very expensive.
You can try with a payed RPC Triton, helius or quicknode for example. Many of them also have free tiers. Here is a list of RPC providers:
https://solana.com/de/rpc

I understood what I did wrong, can I ask you more about the issue I have token: https://solscan.io/token/7iDXK2j7FKNGXMAAyXqRn2JRtf5Nn2YAVgSyuu6Fpump
How can I detech which smartcontract created this token, so that I can detech which contracts have tokens created similar to the above token

This token was created with the standart token program: https://explorer.solana.com/address/TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA and probably using https://pump.fun

I really appreciate your support, I'm actually practicing on that site and want to detech all the pools on pump fun, can you give me some directions?

Sorry i dont know, you can try make another question on how to find all pump.fun pools. Maybe they have an api?
